# Refresh with AjaxRequestTarget but with feedbacks

Tags: java, wicket

When I add a component to `AjaxRequestTarget`, all the feedbacks that it contained are cleared. Is there any way to disable this? I want to change something in component but I want all the feedback to still be visible.

edit: I user wicket 1.4.18

Answer (score 0):

add just what you want to draw to AjaxRequestTarget, in other worlds dont add the feedback panels or any parent container

Comment: then you can visit all childrens of the container
Visits all children of the specified parent container and adds them to the target if they are of same type as childCriteria
target.addChildren(parent, childCriteria);